# What are the pros and cons of using GroovyClassLoader vs. GroovyShell

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell, groovyclassloader

I need to run some external code from my Java application that will be updated frequently and orthogonally to the rest of the application. As I do not to re-deploy the entire application for every code change (and for other reasons as well) we chose to use [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) for this code, and store it either on the file system or in the database.

[From the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) I understand I have two ways to run the code - Using the [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) or the [GroovyClassLoader](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html) (eval does not fit here)

What are the pros and cons of each method?

Answer (score 3):

GroovyShell uses GroovyClassLoader underneath. Use GroovyShell unless you need a feature that's only provided by GroovyClassLoader.

Comment: But does the GroovyShell cache the executed script?

Comment: im no expert im just starting my own groovyshell embedding but the compilerconfiguration class includes /**
     * Gets the target directory for writing classes.
     */
    public File getTargetDirectory() {
        return this.targetDirectory;
    }

Answer (score 2):

GroovyShell uses the default classloader until you load something in a script that customizes the classpath, then it switches to a custom GroovyClassLoader, which can cause problems loading some jdbc drivers or jndi items, etc...  So, if your default classloader already has the classpath it needs and , and if you can avoid instantiating a new GroovyClassLoader object in your Java code, then loading a shell script with a simple GroovyShell will use the default classloader and you'll be better off for it.

Hope I understood your question.

Comment: I have a Java application which wraps some logic which is written in a custom DSL in groovy. The code of the Java app changes seldom, the groovy code (the DSL) is changed frequently. I don't wont the DSL code to be interpreted every time, but to be compiled to bytecode for later executions. Can the GroovyShell do it?

Comment: If your intention is to compile into bytecode, then why use Groovy?  Also, the part that changes frequently seems suitable to be compiled dynamically rather than pre-compiled.  Personally, for a DSL, I would have used XTend rather than Groovy.  Each person has their own preferences.

Comment: Changes frequently means that a single script can be changed once a month, but there are total of dozens of changes a day (we have over 2500 scripts we manage). So we have enough changes that we do not want a re-deploy, but each code is changed seldom, so I want it to be complied. Regarding XTend - it looks nice, but the questions are (a) can I load it dynamically; and (b) what is the size of the community behind it.